# Extending ScrollView according to the information inside and saving?

Tags: xcode, swift, uiscrollview, save, uitextfield

I am trying to create a `ScrollView` that grows according to the amount of information added to it and save the data. How can I accomplish this? I have been trying to figure this out for a while and am unsure of how to do it. The data that I want to save is inside a TextField. I am unsure if this could cause any problems.

Any input and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is this any different from a table view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.contentSize` of a UIScrollView to set the content size.
If you want to base the content size of the size of the information, you could expand the content size every time you add new content

```
var scrollView:UIScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200))
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(100, 800)

var textField:UITextField = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(0, scrollView.frame.height, scrollView.frame.width, 200))

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.contentSize.width, scrollView.contentSize.height + textField.frame.height)
scrollView.addSubview(textField)
textField.text = "Foo"


var lbls = [String]()
for view in scrollView.subviews{
    if let view:UITextField = view as? UITextField{
        var lbl = view.text
    }
}

//Save lbls as array or every string inside lbls using core data
```

Here I set the height of the content size to the height of my label + the current height of the content size.

Comment: How would I save the data inside the SrollView even when I exit the app?

Comment: In this case loop through all the subviews of the UIScrollView get the UILabel’s text element and save them all.
If you have another object that you want to add in the scrollview save that object to your CoreData. **EDIT:** Sorry just read you want to save the info from a TextField, these also have a .text element so you could just save them as NSString’s in your cordite

Comment: Edited the code for you, there are excellent tutorials out there to find more info regarding core data; it would be excessive to explain that here now, i’d advice to google how to use the core data to save the strings if you don’t know already